# Best way to ping for the API changes in the wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, api

I am importing the posts into the wordpress from external API's , i have created the plugin for this, posts are imported successfully. but now i am going to implement auto check for the new API changes and if new posts exists on the API then import that post into the wordpress. 
What is the best way to implement this ?
Can i request the API URL after a certain amount of time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to trigger a hook used in your plugin to request the API URL after a certain amount of time.

Comment: It will be nice if you can add some snippet of psedu code that illustrates the use of the technique and not only a link to RTFM ;)

Comment: There are already working code examples at the link provided.

Comment: As I said RTFM do not make a good answer and the codex is obsolete in any case